Laravel Eloquent hasMany relationship only return 1 value
i am casting an array
[1,2]
and in my model I have this setup
    protected $casts = [
      'skills' => 'array'
    ];

and I have my relationship setup like this
    public function skills(){
      return $this->hasMany(Skill::class,'id');
    }

now my problem is my skills relationship only returns the first value here is the return data
            "skills": [
             {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Angularjs",
                "created_at": "2024-10-08T05:03:38.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2024-10-08T05:03:38.000000Z"
             }
           ]


Remove the cast to array
relation as same
public function skills()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Skill::class, 'id', 'skills');
}

used the accessor like this
public function getSkillsAttribute($value)
{
   $skillIds = json_decode($value, true); 
   return Skill::whereIn('id', $skillIds)->get();
}


To quote the Laravel docs:
Attributes that are null will not be cast. In addition, you should never define a cast (or an attribute) that has the same name as a relationship or assign a cast to the model's primary key.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting
That said, the cast as defined above would cast a JSON database column called "skills" to an array. This will not work for a relationship.
To access the relationship data as an array, either do
  $yourModelInstance->skills()->all();

to get an array of Skill instances (objects), or
  $yourModelInstance->skills->toArray()

to get an array of Skills that are cast into an associative array.
It also looks like the variable dump is JSON, probably from Javascript. If you are passing data to a frontend, it might be a good idea to look into Eloquent Resources: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-resources
It is a good practice to define how to deliver data to the frontend that doesn't accidentally contain data you don't need or don't want to be posted to the frontend. You can also use the $hidden or $visible properties on any Model.

it is possible you are forgeting something.for example check the deleted at column of your database table,maybe you have used soft delete,and table still is showing the data,If not,please send me more info to help you

The issue is that you are trying to cast a method which is not a column that is wrong if you want to cast or change the result to array use this approch
$yourModel->skills->toArray()

And lastly, the problem with it returning one result is that it's trying to fetch a row using the Skill model that matches the model id assuming the Skill have the id as primary_key; there will only be one element in that table in skills table that matches YourModel id that was the reason that was returning 1 data, to correct that, remove the id and replace it with the foreign_key For more reference, use this link: laravel doc
public function skills(){
      return $this->hasMany(Skill::class,'foreign_key');
    }

